# Suggestion for the phrase "go under the question ..."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

Suppose that I want to explain why we select the students using specific metrics. I've written down:

1. > if we choose the students indiscriminately, the fairness goes under the question.
2. > if we choose the students indiscriminately, the fairness is questionable.
3. > Selecting the students indiscriminately makes the fairness questionable.

---

Question:
Would you please provide me with better sentences and phrases?

---

Personally, I prefer to use phrases similar to "go + under + question". Such phrases are very common in my native language (Persian). Also, for me, It is interesting to see whether English-spoken people use such phrases or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I have never heard of "something goes under question" said in a sentence. And "indiscriminately" is used with negative statements such as "he killed indiscriminately". You might want to say "If we choose the students randomly, it throws fairness into question." Though I still don't understand what you exactly mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Selecting the students indiscriminately makes fairness questionable.
>   Selecting the students indiscriminately makes **the** fairness of it (all) questionable.

is correct meaning the selection process has flaws and questions.

> If we choose the students indiscriminately, then fairness **becomes** a question.
>   if we choose the students indiscriminately, fairness may **becomes** a question.
>   If we choose the students indiscriminately, fairness may **become** questionable.

might be a better phrasing for the hypothetical outcome.

The strange part about your statement is that choosing students **indiscriminately** (without discrimination) is the same as **at random** which can be deemed as **fair**.  The problem is usually when there is some type of **discrimination** involved.

> If we are not careful with our selection metrics, they may be questioned for discrimination.

To **go under question** is more a legal term for questioning a suspected criminal

> he was put **under question** at the police station

and would not really apply to something inanimate like a selection process.